# Templating engines in Compound JS

Tags: node.js, pug, compoundjs

I was trying to set jade as my default template engine in compound js. As i was going through the documentation i found

> **Templating engines**
>
> By default railway use ejs templating engine, but you can switch to jade, using settings
>
> ```
> app.set('view engine', 'jade');
> ```
>
> and add line
>
> ```
> require('jade-ext');
> ```
>
> to ./npmfile.js

But I was not able to find the file that i have to edit.

can you point out which file to edit to change the template engine?

Now i added the `app.set` But where to find `npmfile.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. It was simple.

I just have to add `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` in config/enviornment.js

Answer (score 1):

The default entry script.  From the docs it looks like it'd be `server.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
  , "jade": "latest"
  , "jade-ext": "latest"
```

to the dependencies in package.json and then ran:

```
npm install
```